# dynamic date array

Tags: php, arrays, date

i'm not so hot with my php.

i was wondering if you could help me, i'm trying to create an array that contains the last 31 dates. e.g.

```
$dates = array("2011-03-22", "2011-03-21", "2011-03-20", "2011-03-19", ........... "2011-02-22");
```

any pointers appreciated :)

thanks

alsweet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, its fairly straight forward. (Available from PHP 5.2 onwards).

```
$dates = array();
$date = new DateTime();
for($i = 0; $i < 31; $i++) {
    $dates[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $date->modify('-1 day');
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks a lot! that is quite straight forward, i'll get there one day :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `DateInterval`:

```
foreach(new DatePeriod(new DateTime("30 days ago"), new DateInterval('P1D'), 30) as $d) 
 $a[] = $d->format('Y-m-d');

$a = array_reverse($a); // assuming you want today to be index 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an older-school method using unix timestamps, `mktime()`, and `date()`.

```
<?php

// mktime() gives you a unix timestamp, with the
// current timestamp returned if you don't supply
// an argument.
$now = mktime();
$dates = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++) {
    // date() allows you to format a unix timestamp.
    // Take now (mktime()), and iteratively substract
    // 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 24 hours (gives you 
    // one day in seconds), and multiply that by the 
    // days-in-seconds offset, or $i, and run that
    // date() to produce the timestamp that date you
    // will use to produce the plaintext formatted date.
    $dates[$i-1] = date('Y-m-d',$now-($i*(60*60*24)));
}

?>
```

If you:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($dates);
```

You get the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2011-03-20
    [1] => 2011-03-19
    [2] => 2011-03-18
    [3] => 2011-03-17
    [4] => 2011-03-16
    [5] => 2011-03-15
    [6] => 2011-03-14
    [7] => 2011-03-13
    [8] => 2011-03-12
    [9] => 2011-03-11
    [10] => 2011-03-10
    [11] => 2011-03-09
    [12] => 2011-03-08
    [13] => 2011-03-07
    [14] => 2011-03-06
    [15] => 2011-03-05
    [16] => 2011-03-04
    [17] => 2011-03-03
    [18] => 2011-03-02
    [19] => 2011-03-01
    [20] => 2011-02-28
    [21] => 2011-02-27
    [22] => 2011-02-26
    [23] => 2011-02-25
    [24] => 2011-02-24
    [25] => 2011-02-23
    [26] => 2011-02-22
    [27] => 2011-02-21
    [28] => 2011-02-20
    [29] => 2011-02-19
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php